# Android SDK thinks there is no space left on my hard drive

Tags: android, installation, sdk

I have been trying most of today to install and use Android 4.1 development SDK. I won't bother anyone with everything I have tried.

It seemed to be operational, but I needed to install an AMD emulator to actually do anything. Using the SDK Tool Kit manager, I have been trying to get it to install the required software, but every time I try I get this error:

Disk usage:

- Estimated download size 91.2 MB
- Estimated disk space to be additionally occupied on SDK partition after installation: 364.7 MB
- Currently available disk space in SDK root(*location of the SDK root*) 0 B

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

I am running on a 4 year old HP laptop with one hard drive partition with 916 of storage and a recovery partition with 13.9 GB. File Manager shows my D drive has 851 GB available.

Comment: Oops...I forgot to mention that the file manager says I have 916 GB of free space on my C drive.

Answer (score 9):

I came up against this while trying to reinstall AS (don't ask why). What seemed to have happened was that after the new install it opened the last project I'd worked on, though I thought I'd removed all user settings.
This meant skipping the start up screen where, heaven knows why, you still have to download the SDK. I was tearing my hair out and finally closed the project,  at which point the start up screen appeared and I could download the SDK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Exactly my problem.  Reinstalled A/S, but it would start up with my previous project. Never asked if I wanted to keep old settings, etc. Trying to install SDK and components kept reporting 0 B free, but disk reported 15GB free.  After closing the project, was immediately taken to the "install SDK and components" screen, and everything moved without issue. Even asked to re-open my old projects again, which loaded and build without issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution in the latest Android was to

1. Remove all sdk files, leave Android Studio.
2. **Close all projects in Android Studio**
3. Launch empty Android Studio and install the Android SDK.

After empty launch with basic SDK installation disk space is calculated properly and you can install required components in SDK manager.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
The reason it is saying 0B is because - you might have deleted the location of the SDK.

1. You have to manually create the folders in the path.
   For example if your SDK path shows on that pop-up is: `/Users/name/Library/Android/sdk`
2. Then go to this path and check if all these folders are available.
   If not, create them.
3. Then come back and click again in the SDK manager.

It will allow you to install and it will show the available sizes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the path that is being used by the Sdk manager.

[image: sdk manager default path]

Just choose the edit option there and select a path that exists or create a new path.
VOILA